# Error while viewing queue consumers

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker, broker

After navigating to Active MQ admin console and then: *Queues* -> *Active consumers* (the one's I'm trying name is prefixed with *private:*) I get:

> Exception occurred while processing this request, check the log for
>   more information!

En extract from the logs:

> ==> activemq.log <== 2017-06-29 08:22:06,564 | WARN  |  | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp948115224-48
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /queueConsumers.jsp at line 60
>
> 57:  58:  59:  60:  61:
>    62:   63:

`/queueConsumers.jsp` line 60 is:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestContext.queueConsumerQuery.consumers}" var="row">
```

What may be the problem, how to solve it?

The version I'm using is: *5.14.5*